# Perform checked on different than value attribute

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to use custom attribute for checked binding in knockout js.
Unfortunately this code doesn't do the job

`<input type="radio" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedPriceRangeLabel, disable: disabled, value: value, attr: {label: label}" />`

```
function vm {
return {
    label: ko.observable(),
    value: ko.observable(),
    isDisabled: ko.observable()...
}
```

}

How can I provide functionality to checking elements basing on their label property?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve... Do you want to add an attribute with a dynamic name?

Comment: What is `$parent.selectedPriceRangeLabel`? Is that a boolean value, because that's the only way it'll show as checked or not.

Comment: Might want to try `checked: $parent.selectedPriceRangeLabel === label`, which would evaluate as a boolean.